# Android Ksoap with WCF .svc endpoint

Tags: android, wcf, soap, svc

so i need to send a SoapObject as a parameter of a SoapObject............ from the request dump above it seems that the envelope structure is fine.......but the server always gets null when i try get "filter.street" from the request......any ideas?

Comment: [Please try again.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4831327/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the ksoap2 android wiki about debugging and check out the request and response.
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks

Comment: i got it working, i had to create a class mapping and define my namespaces for each parameter. when it comes to wcf and ksoap, namespaces are a show stopper!

Comment: I would be happy to include your tips on the project wiki and accept patches as well..